# jquery get value inside array of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the  following function which returns to me value in form of json :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>Travel/get_kyc_details",
            datatype: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                $.each(data, function (i, key) {
                    console.log(key);
                });



            }, error: function (data) {
            }
        });
```

The data returned is in the  following format :

```
{
  "6": {   
    "phone_no_prefix": 254,
    "phone_no": 714339521,
    "contact_name": "Sammy Ojwang",
    "contact_phone_prefix": 254,
    "contact_phone": 77528578,
    "contact_email": "smjwang@gmail.com",
    "passport": "A1730170",
    "national_id": 28200148
  },
  "7": {  
    "phone_no_prefix": 254,
    "phone_no": 700000000,
    "contact_name": "Emergency One",
    "contact_phone_prefix": 254,
    "contact_phone": 7100000,
    "contact_email": "em@gmail.com",
    "passport": "A189234",
    "national_id": 12345678
  },
  "8": { 
    "phone_no_prefix": 254,
    "phone_no": 711111111,
    "contact_name": "Emergency Two",
    "contact_phone_prefix": 254,
    "contact_phone": 7130000,
    "contact_email": "em2@gmail.com",
    "passport": "A8765432",
    "national_id": 981234
  }
}
```

However, when I try to loop through it using the following format, it fails  :

```
$.each(data, function (i, key) {
                    console.log(key);
                });
```

The following is the  error I get :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"9":
```

How can I loop through and retrieve the  data in : 
phone_no_prefix , contact_name, national_id, contact_email etc ?

Comment: That's not an array but a key-value pair object.  An alternative `$.each(Object.entries(data), function (i, [key,value]) {
                    console.log(key, '/', value);
                });`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to iterate and print the values using the same method:

```
var data = {
  "6": {   
    "phone_no_prefix": 254,
    "phone_no": 714339521,
    "contact_name": "Sammy Ojwang",
    "contact_phone_prefix": 254,
    "contact_phone": 77528578,
    "contact_email": "smjwang@gmail.com",
    "passport": "A1730170",
    "national_id": 28200148
  },
  "7": {  
    "phone_no_prefix": 254,
    "phone_no": 700000000,
    "contact_name": "Emergency One",
    "contact_phone_prefix": 254,
    "contact_phone": 7100000,
    "contact_email": "em@gmail.com",
    "passport": "A189234",
    "national_id": 12345678
  },
  "8": { 
    "phone_no_prefix": 254,
    "phone_no": 711111111,
    "contact_name": "Emergency Two",
    "contact_phone_prefix": 254,
    "contact_phone": 7130000,
    "contact_email": "em2@gmail.com",
    "passport": "A8765432",
    "national_id": 981234
  }
}

$.each(data, function(key,value){ console.log(value) });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to support IE browser you have to iterate over [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then using these keys do whatever you need:

```js
const data = {
  "6": {   
    "phone_no_prefix": 254,
    "phone_no": 714339521,
    "contact_name": "Sammy Ojwang",
    "contact_phone_prefix": 254,
    "contact_phone": 77528578,
    "contact_email": "smjwang@gmail.com",
    "passport": "A1730170",
    "national_id": 28200148
  },
  "7": {  
    "phone_no_prefix": 254,
    "phone_no": 700000000,
    "contact_name": "Emergency One",
    "contact_phone_prefix": 254,
    "contact_phone": 7100000,
    "contact_email": "em@gmail.com",
    "passport": "A189234",
    "national_id": 12345678
  },
  "8": { 
    "phone_no_prefix": 254,
    "phone_no": 711111111,
    "contact_name": "Emergency Two",
    "contact_phone_prefix": 254,
    "contact_phone": 7130000,
    "contact_email": "em2@gmail.com",
    "passport": "A8765432",
    "national_id": 981234
  }
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){
 console.log(data[key]);
});
```

It's a vanilla js ES5 approach which will work in every browser and no jQuery methods are needed.